# MVC Nested Collection Models Where Child has Child of Its Own Type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I am working with a very complex Model and binding. I have so far been able to use the code setup [here](http://www.itorian.com/2013/04/nested-collection-models-in-mvc-to-add_12.html) to make things work. However, one of the nested models can have itself as a nested model. When I put the same kind of setup in the editor template, it creates an infinite loop and causes a stack overflow error. I can't go into extreme detail of my actual code because of privacy issues, but my model is set up something like this:

**Parent Object:**

Field 1

Field 2

Collection of Child Objects

**Child Object:**

Field A

Field B

Collection of Child Objects

The Collections in both objects can be empty. Here's a simplified example of the "Parent" View:

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("LetterEntry", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Field1)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Field1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Field1)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Field2)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Field2)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Field2)
        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="editor-label" id="ChildFieldsLabel">
                @Html.Label("Has child fields?")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field" id="ChildFieldsField">
                @Html.CheckBox("ChildFieldsCheckBox", new { @onclick = "ChildFieldsChecked(this)" })
            </div>
            <div class="display-none" id="outer-ChildFieldsDiv">
                <div id="ChildFieldsDiv">
                    @* individual child field entries go here *@
                </div>
                @Html.AddLink("Add Child Field", "#ChildFieldsDiv", ".child-field-single-div", "ChildFields", typeof(Project.Datalayer.ChildFields))
            </div>
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
}
```

And the Child Editor Template:

```html
<div class="required-field-single-div">
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FieldA)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FieldA)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FieldA)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FieldB)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FieldB)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FieldB)
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="editor-label" id="ChildFieldsLabel">
            @Html.Label("Has sub-requirements?")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field-noborder" id="ChildFieldsField">
            @Html.CheckBox("Sub-ChildFieldsCheckBox", new { @onclick = "Sub-ChildFieldsChecked(this)" })
        </div>
        <div class="display-none" id="outer-Sub-ChildFieldsDiv">
            <div id="Sub-ChildFieldsDiv">
                @* individual child entries go here *@
            </div>
            @Html.AddLink("Add Sub-Child Field", "#Sub-ChildFieldsDiv", ".child-field-single-div", "ChildFields.ChildFields", typeof(Project.Datalayer.ChildFields))
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

I'm not including the Javascript for the checkboxes because all it does is display the hidden div. Everything is working perfectly until I add in the AddLink line in the Child Editor Template.

Exact error is: {Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}

I have stepped through the AddLink code, and determined that the error occurs on the "Editor For(nestedObject)" portion here:

```js
public static IHtmlString AddLink<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, string linkText, string containerElement, string counterElement, string collectionProperty, Type nestedType)
        {
            var ticks = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
            var nestedObject = Activator.CreateInstance(nestedType);
            var partial = htmlHelper.EditorFor(x => nestedObject).ToHtmlString().JsEncode();
            partial = partial.Replace("id=\\\"nestedObject", "id=\\\"" + collectionProperty + "_" + ticks + "_");
            partial = partial.Replace("name=\\\"nestedObject", "name=\\\"" + collectionProperty + "[" + ticks + "]");
            var js = string.Format("javascript:addNestedForm('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}');return false;", containerElement, counterElement, ticks, partial);
            TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("a");
            tb.Attributes.Add("href", "#");
            tb.Attributes.Add("onclick", js);
            tb.InnerHtml = linkText;
            var tag = tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag);
        }
```

I have done a ton of searching to try and find an answer, but I can only find information about nested models with more lists as you get deeper. I haven't found anything about when a child object in the model can have a child of its own type.

I'm at a total loss at this point, so any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello. What error are you getting? Where is the code for the method you call when you get that error?

Comment: @derloopkat The error is {Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}, and the method is already in the post--the "AddLink" code. It's the last code sample.

Comment: "However, one of the nested models can have itself as a nested model." You say that the child class can have a list of child class objects on it but that isn't the same as having itself as a property (which is what is causing the exception).  There should never be a reason for an object to have itself on it.

Comment: I guess I didn't state it correctly. It cannot have itself as a property, but it can have objects of its own type as a property. The error is occurring because of a circular reference when the AddLink code tries to create the javascript. It keeps trying to generate more and more nested code because it sees the AddLink within itself. The javascript that it generates includes a copy of the editor template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bunch of trial and error, I created a JavaScript-only solution to my problem. The parent View still uses the original code, but this is the new Child Editor Template:

```html
<div class="required-field-single-div">
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FieldA)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FieldA)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FieldA)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FieldB)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FieldB)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FieldB)
    </div>

    <div class="single-field">
        <div id="outer-SubChildFieldsDiv">
            <div id="SubChildFieldsDiv">
                @* individual entries go here*@
            </div>
            @{ string jsText = "addNestedForm2('#SubChildFieldsDiv','.sub-child-field-single-div','ChildFields[0].ChildFields1')"; }
            <a href="#" onclick=@jsText>Add Sub-Child Field</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

And the new functions in the JavaScript file:

```js
function addNestedForm2(container, counter, collectionProperty) {
    var nextIndex = $(counter).length;
    var nestPattern = new RegExp("nestedObject", "gi");
    var countPattern = new RegExp("ReplaceMeWithCount", "gi");
    var counterPattern = new RegExp("counterClass", "gi");
    var incrementedIdPattern = new RegExp("incrementedId", "gi");
    var counterObj = document.getElementById("counter");
    var incrementedId = Number.parseInt(counterObj.value);
    var counterClass = counter.substring(1);
    var content = ReturnContent().replace(nestPattern, collectionProperty).replace(countPattern, nextIndex)
                                 .replace(counterPattern, counterClass).replace(incrementedIdPattern, incrementedId);
    counterObj.value = incrementedId + 1;
    $(container).append(content);
};

function ReturnContent() {
    var content = "<div class=\"child-field-single-div counterClass\">" +
    "<div class=\"editor-label-noborder\">        " +
    "<label for=\"nestedObject_FieldA\">FieldA</label>    " +
    "</div>    " +
    "<div class=\"editor-field-noborder\">        " +
    "<input class=\"check-box\" id=\"nestedObject_ReplaceMeWithCount__FieldA\" name=\"nestedObject[ReplaceMeWithCount].FieldA\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"true\" />" +
    "<input name=\"nestedObject[ReplaceMeWithCount].FieldA\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"false\" />        " +
    "<span class=\"field-validation-valid\" data-valmsg-for=\"nestedObject.FieldA\" data-valmsg-replace=\"true\"></span>    " +
    "</div>    " +
    "<div class=\"editor-label-noborder\">        " +
    "<label for=\"nestedObject_FieldB\">FieldB</label>    " +
    "</div>    " +
    "<div class=\"editor-field-noborder\">        " +
    "<input class=\"text-box single-line\" id=\"nestedObject_ReplaceMeWithCount__FieldB\" name=\"nestedObject[ReplaceMeWithCount].FieldB\" type=\"text\" value=\"\" />        " +
    "<span class=\"field-validation-valid\" data-valmsg-for=\"nestedObject.FieldB\" data-valmsg-replace=\"true\"></span>    " +
    "</div>    " +        
    "</div>" +
    "<div id=\"outer-SubChildFieldsDiv\">      " +      
    "<div id=\"SubChildFieldsDiv_incrementedId\">               " +
    "</div\>            " +
    "<a href=\"#\" onclick=addNestedForm2('#SubChildFieldsDiv_incrementedId','.child-field-single-div_incrementedId','nestedObject[ReplaceMeWithCount].ChildFields1')\>Add Sub-Child Field</a\>                        " +
    "</div\>    ";

    return content;
};
```

The code in the ReturnContent function was pulled from the developer tools in chrome and is an edited version of what is generated, though it is basically the same as the Child Editor Template. The incrementedId object in the code is used to ensure that each new level is uniquely identified and will link up to the proper parent object. I also added a hidden input field to the beginning of the parent view:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="counter" id="counter" value="0">
```

It's not very reusable as-is, but I think it could easily be edited to be more generic and have multiple "returnContent" functions to return the necessary content for whatever Editor Template is being used.

Hopefully this will be helpful if someone else runs into the same issue with the AddLink code.